# A disconnected simple polygon.

Tags: geometry, polygons

Let's say that the definition of a simple polygon is a compact region in the plane whose boundary is a simple piecewise-linear closed curve.

Given this definition, I've noticed that people sometimes explicitly mention that a given simple polygon is connected.

My question is: Is the fact that a polygon is connected not the case by definition? Am I missing something, and a polygon might satisfy the definition above, but the disconnected?

Comment: "people sometimes explicitly mention that a given simple polygon is connected." - it's usually a good idea to provide links for such statements.

Comment: By "polygon" you mean a closed region whose boundary is made of connected line segments ? If such is the case, as the boundary is connected, the region itself is therefore connected.